# Take first 3 numbers if they meet specified condition

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with column with numbers.

| Year | Customer | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 530010 | 11728.7 |
| 2022 | 540060 | 4793.21 |
| 2022 | 514008 | -15665.40 |
| 2022 | 540860 | 6991.10 |
| 2022 | 540060 | 1382.00 |

Now I want to pick the first 3 numbers if they match a certain condition

###### e.g. if column values start with 540 or 514 then we give me the first 3 numbers otherwise give the full number

```
def first_three(val):
    return val[:3] 
   if len(val) > 3 else val
```

But I want only the first 3 numbers only if they match the my specified condition

Thanks in advance

Comment: Added a purely pandas solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
def first_three(val):
    aaa = str(val)
    bbb = int(aaa[:3])
    qqq = 0
    if bbb == 514 or bbb == 540:
        qqq = bbb
    else:
        qqq = val
    return qqq 


print(first_three(514008))
```

The number is turned into a string, the first three elements are taken and converted back to int.
Where in the verification process we choose which number to return.

```
df['Customer1'] = df['Customer'].astype('str').str[:3]
index = (df['Customer1'] != '514') & (df['Customer1'] != '540')
df.loc[index, 'Customer1'] = df.loc[index, 'Customer']
df['Customer1'] = df['Customer1'].astype(int)
```

If done purely on pandas, then the solution is as follows. The column is 'Customer' copied and converted to string, the first three characters are also left in it. Next, we find indices where there are no rows 514 and 540.
For these indices, we fill in the values that do not match with 514 and 540. Let's convert the column back to int type.

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '   '`

Comment: I have 514 displayed in print. val is my number, what I pass to the function when printing.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Year': [2022, 2022,2022],
     'Customer': [530010, 540060,514008],
    'Price':[11728.7,4793.21,-15665.40]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['new_columns']=[int(str(val)[0:3]) if (str(val)[0:3]=='540') or (str(val)[0:3]=='514') else val for val in df['Customer'].values  ]
df
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in the following way.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Year': [2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022],
    'Customer': [530010, 540060, 514008, 540860, 540060],
    'Price': [11728.7, 4793.21, -15665.40, 6991.10, 1382.00]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df['new_column'] = [int(str(val)[0:3]) if (str(val)[0:3] in (
    '540', '514')) else val for val in df['Customer'].values]

print(df)

   Year  Customer     Price  new_column
0  2022    530010  11728.70      530010
1  2022    540060   4793.21         540
2  2022    514008 -15665.40         514
3  2022    540860   6991.10         540
4  2022    540060   1382.00         540
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `str.extract` and `Series.mask`

```py
m = df['Customer'].astype(str).str.extract('^(540|514)')[0]
df['col'] = df['Customer'].mask(m.notna(), m)
```

```
print(df)

   Year  Customer     Price     col
0  2022    530010  11728.70  530010
1  2022    540060   4793.21     540
2  2022    514008 -15665.40     514
3  2022    540860   6991.10     540
4  2022    540060   1382.00     540
```